# Synonym for 'first class' as in 'first gathering of a course'

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for the most colloquial synonym for the term 'first class', in the meaning of 'first gathering of a course'. My reason for looking for an alternative is that 'first class' is too easily read as 'first-class', as in 'top-notch'.
Would 'opening class' be correct and normal-sounding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe "first meeting" or "first session" or "first lecture."

Comment: "on the first day of our class ... "

Comment: "The first class of Linguistics 101 will be held on Wednesday, Sept 7th at 09:30."  You don't need an alternate expression; context will tell.

Comment: *Introductory session* and the somewhat more festive-sounding *opening day* are further possibilities.

Comment: Please write an example sentence where you would use the phrase. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Example sentence: _"The unclear instructions in the syllabus invariably made each first class a confusing affair"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to propose [***initial***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/initial) class.

> Existing or occurring at the beginning:
>   *our initial impression was favourable*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/initial

Comment: ~ it's technically correct but you should mention that using 'initial' in this context is liable to make you come off as highfalutin, i.e. it's not very colloquial language